# Detect read-only domain controller with .NET?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I want to be able to determine whether a particular domain controller is read-only.  I know I can do stuff like this to get a writeable DC:

```
using( Domain d = Domain.GetCurrentDomain() )
{ 
    DomainController dc = d.FindDomainController(
        "mysitename", LocatorOptions.WriteableRequired);
}
```

But given a DomainController object is there a way to determine whether that DC is writeable?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to try to select a preferred domain controller that is 1. Writeable 2. In my site and 3. a global catalog.  There doesn't seem to be a good way to find a server with all these attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One difference between Read-Only and Writable Domain Controllers are that all Read-Only Domain Controllers have the attribute `primaryGroupID` set to 521 (which is the RID for the "Read-only Domain Controllers" built-in group in Active Directory). Writable Domain Controllers have `primaryGroupID` set to 516 (the "Domain Controllers" group).

The primary group for a read-only domain controller cannot be easily changed (Active Directory won't allow it) so you should be safe to assume that all RODC:s have that attribute set to 521.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but...

If you have the DomainController object, you can do:

```
bool isWritable = true;
try
{
    using (Domain d = Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
        var dc = d.FindDomainController(theDomainController.Name, LocatorOptions.WriteableRequired);
}
catch(ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException)
{
    isWritable = false;
}
```

This should determine whether a specific domain controller is writable.

Comment: That doesn't work. The first parameter of FindDomainController is the name of the site to search not the domain controller hostname.  If you try that code, it will set isWritable = false for all domain controllers.